# X3 reunion tutorial?

Tags: pc, x3-terran-conflict

I got X3 off of Steam for cheap recently.  I have never played any of the X games before, and I am finding it difficult to get started.  There is no in game tutorial to teach you the controls and how to play it.

So how do I get started?  I don't want a walk through I just want to learn the controls so I can enjoy the universe.

Comment: Would recommend you to start directly with X3: Terran conflict, though, if you bought the pack with both of them, as it is about the same, with a better interface, better to start directly from there, if you have it.

Comment: I did get the pack.  I will do that.

Comment: good, because X3:TC adds an easier interface with mouse (the original is really a lot about keyboard shortcuts), and "free mouse" control of the ship, for fights and navigation in general. X3:TC is a stand alone expansion pack, so it's not like if you were playing a sequel and missing on the story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developers' forum is a great resource.  I spent a lot of time here reading posts about X3 before I really figured out how to play it.  There is a wealth of great information in these forums.

http://forum.egosoft.com/viewforum.php?f=2

Answer (score 5):

Allow me to provide a few links that you might find helpful (I sure did):

1. [The Ultimate X resource and guides list](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=162408)
2. [X-Universe Plugin Manager](http://cycrow.thexuniverse.us/) (for when you branch out beyond the basic game and use mods)
3. [A site with maps, guides, etc](http://eng.x3tc.ru/).
4. And finally a buddy of mine (Faust) posted a *ton* of helpful stuff in response to a blog posting of mine. You can find it [here at this link](http://phileosophos.com/wordpress/?p=47).

Take a look at those resources. They helped me get beyond the hump when I was pretty stymied by the learning curve. It's a fantastic game once you get into it.

Answer (score 3):

I started playing X3:TC recently and I've found the [X3TC Walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2BC4835802365FF1&feature=plcp) series of tutorial videos by [CdrDave](http://www.youtube.com/user/CdrDave) incredibly helpful.